# Restore a table from another table

Tags: t-sql

SQL Server 2000

I backup a table like below:

```
select * into bkp_table from src_table;
```

How can I restore from backup table to source table? Truncate the src_table? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
truncate table src_table

insert src_table
select * from bkp_table
```

now if you have an identity column, you need to do `SET IDENTITY_INSERT src_table ON` after the truncate (the truncate will reset it to 0 BTW)

Then do you insert and then `SET IDENTITY_INSERT src_table OFF`

Answer (score 2):

1.Truncate the table

2.Insert back records in to the table, keeping the same Identity as in Backup

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT src_table ON

INSERT src_table(TheIdentity, TheValue)
SELECT * FROM bkp_table

SET IDENTITY_INSERT src_table OFF
```